# Send array data from one class to another JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

(I'm a beginner so this may sound obvious/lack information.) I have an ArrayList of attributes for different pets including attributes such as their given-name, common-name, the price of the animal, sex, date bought and date sold.   this information is generated from a separate class that adds an array of information to an array of arrays of the already existing list of animals. Essentially, I want to send the array to another class (called Pets) so it can then be added to the array of arrays. I understand this may sound confusing but this is the only way I can word it, I can clarify anything if needed. Any help would be great as I'm really stuck and can't work out how to send it. This is the code that generates my values in the array (using text-boxes to input the information).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ArrayList<String> NewanimalArr = new ArrayList<>();

            String givenName = txtGivenname.getText();
            String commonName = txtCommonName.getText();
            String priceOf = txtPrice_1.getText();
            String sexOf = txtSex.getText();
            String colourOf = txtMaincolour.getText();
            String dateOfA = txtArrivaldate.getText();
            String dateSold = txtSellingdate.getText();

            NewanimalArr.add(givenName);
            NewanimalArr.add(commonName);
            NewanimalArr.add(priceOf);
            NewanimalArr.add(sexOf);
            NewanimalArr.add(colourOf);
            NewanimalArr.add(dateOfA);
            NewanimalArr.add(dateSold);

            System.out.println(NewanimalArr);
        }
    });
```

this will then print information generated that is entered for example:
[alex, Dog, 40.50, Male, Brown, 14/04/2015, 14/12/2016]
how do I then send this data to another class

Comment: There is nothing like "sending data" somewhere. You can make `newAnimalArr` (sidenote: PLEASE abide by the naming conventions) a field of your class which would make it accessible everywhere in your class. I would however highly recommend you to just have a look at a tutorial on Java. There is no reason to frustrate yourself over things that are simply above your current level of knowledge. Read a tutorial, do it step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Option one `Constructor Injection`:

```
public class Foo {
  List<String> actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    List<String> newanimalArr = new ArrayList<>();
    .....
    return newanimalArr
}
...
public class Pets {
  private final List<String> array;
  public Pets(final List<String> array) {
    this.array = array;
  }
  void bar() {
    System.out.println(this.array);
  }
}
....
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Pets pets = new Pets(foo.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent() ) );
  pets.bar();
}
```

Option two `Getter-Setter Injection`:

```
public class Foo {
   private final List<String> newanimalArr;
   public Foo() {
     this.newanimalArr = new ArrayList<>();
   }  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    .....
   }
   public List<String> getNewanimalArr() {
      return new ArrayList<String>(newanimalArr);
   }
}
...
public class Pets {
  private List<String> array;
  public Pets() {
    this.array = Collections.<String>emptyList();
  }
  public void setArray(final List<String> array) {
    this.array = array;  
  }
  public void bar() {
    System.out.println(this.array);
  }
}
....
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent() );
  Pets pets = new Pets();
  bar.setArray( foo.getNewanimalArr() );
  pets.bar();
}
```

See also [Dependency Injection Patterns](https://www.journaldev.com/2394/java-dependency-injection-design-pattern-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class definition of `Pet`, using instance variables for the fields. In Java it is custom to create a `setXyz` and a `getXyz` for each `xyz` field. You can also create a constructor in which you pass all the values and assign them to the fields, this minimizes the risk of fields not being filled in.
The initial `ArrayList` you are creating doesn't add that much use, it is easier to create the `Pet` instances directly:

```
List<Pet> newArrivals = new ArrayList<>();
// get data from view fields and if necessary transform them to other objects such as:
LocalDate arrivedOn = LocalDate.parse(txtArrivaldate.getText(), DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FormatStyle);
// create and add a new Pet object to the list
newArrivals.add(new Pet(.....));

public class Pet {
public enum Gender {
    FEMALE, MALE
}

private String givenName;
private String commonName;
private double price;
private Gender gender;
private String color;
private LocalDate arrivedOn;
private LocalDate soldOn;

public Pet() {
}

public Pet(String givenName, String commonName, double price, Gender gender, String color, LocalDate arrivedOn,
        LocalDate soldOn) {
    super();
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.commonName = commonName;
    this.price = price;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.color = color;
    this.arrivedOn = arrivedOn;
    this.soldOn = soldOn;
}

public String getGivenName() {
    return givenName;
}

public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
}

public String getCommonName() {
    return commonName;
}

public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
    this.commonName = commonName;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(Gender gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public LocalDate getArrivedOn() {
    return arrivedOn;
}

public void setArrivedOn(LocalDate arrivedOn) {
    this.arrivedOn = arrivedOn;
}

public LocalDate getSoldOn() {
    return soldOn;
}

public void setSoldOn(LocalDate soldOn) {
    this.soldOn = soldOn;
}
```

}